# lldb fails to resume

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

lldb stopped in visual debugger, visual output
is corrupt, and it fails to contunue

```
(lldb) c
Process 892 resuming
(lldb) c
Process 892 resuming
(lldb) c
Process 892 resuming
(lldb) c 10
error: The 'process continue' command does not take any arguments.
(lldb) c
Process 892 resuming
(lldb)
```

Is there anything a user can do short of killing and starting new debug session?

UPD20190930:
[image]

Comment: There isn't enough information here to make a guess as to what is going on.  Is the process stopping between these continues?  Xcode at least suppresses the stop notification in the console, since it shows that in the UI, so it wouldn't be in this trace.  If it is stopping, what is the stop reason?

Comment: Initially it stopped on breakpoint. But it failed to resume. This is not the first time I'm seeing this failure to resume.

Comment: We'll have to reproduce this to figure out what's going on.  If you have something that shows this behavior that you can share, can you file a bug, either with http://bugs.llvm.org or http://bugreporter.apple.com?  That's probably the best way to deal with this.

Comment: When you say "stopped on breakpoint" was the stop message something like "breakpoint 1.1" or was it EXC_BREAKPOINT?

Comment: In the past after smth like "breakpoint 1.1" it was also failing to resume. But I'm not sure about the last incident.

Comment: I ask because the stop reason EXC_BREAKPOINT means that you have hit a trap instruction that lldb didn't put in the code.  Other system components use this as a assert, for things like index overflow.  On ARM, the trap instruction doesn't get executed, so the PC is left pointing to the trap, and if you continue, you'll just stop at the trap again.  But if it's a real breakpoint, I don't see how this could happen so we'll have to see it live to figure it out.

Comment: just got a breakpoint  X.Y ; after (lldb) c that ended up as Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)

Comment: Was the pc value when you hit "Breakpoint X.Y" the same as the pc when you hit the EXC_BREAKPOINT?  If they were different, then you are hitting the lldb breakpoint, then continuing onto a trap that's actually in the code.  If the pc at the lldb breakpoint and at the subsequent EXC_BREAKPOINT were the same, that either means you've had the bad luck to put an lldb breakpoint right on a trap instruction that exists in the code (you can disassemble the code to see that) or that you've uncovered an lldb bug with breakpoint handling.  If the latter, if you can file it that would be helpful.